# What's the difference between CRA picture and BLA picture?

Tags: hevc

According to HEVC spec:

A clean random access (CRA) picture may have associated random access skipped leading (RASL) or random access decodable leading (RADL) pictures present in the bitstream.

A broken link access (BLA) picture having nal_unit_type equal to BLA_W_LP may have associated RASL or RADL pictures present in the bitstream. A BLA picture having nal_unit_type equal to BLA_W_RADL does not have associated RASL pictures present in the bitstream, but may have associated RADL pictures in the bitstream. A BLA picture having nal_unit_type equal to BLA_N_LP does not have associated leading pictures present in the bitstream

Except the containing different NAL_unit type, there seems to be no difference between CRA and BLA with nal_unit_type equal to BLA_W_LP.

Any difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLA pictures are very similar to CRA pictures but the main difference is, it is used for concatenating different streams (spliced video). When you concatenate two HEVC streams of different properties (like resolution, GOP, CUSize etc) CRA pictures are converted to BLA pictures. In case of CRA pictures both RASL and RADL pictures are decoded and displayed if it is not a random access where as in case of BLA pictures, RASL pictures are ignored even if it is not a random access.